# How to update profile name of user in drawer widget in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, drawer

Please help me , I want to update profile name and email id of user in drawer widget.

Comment: Please provide more details. Instead of briefly mentioning your end goal, try to share some code snippets, explain the problem you have encountered and what you have tried to do to fix it.

Comment: Following on from what tomas has said, explain what you want to achieve (update profile name & user ID), how you are currently trying to achieve it while referring to code snippets and lastly from here you can explain what isn't working - is your program failing or are you stuck on a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can update profle name and email as follow:

```
... 
return Drawer(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
        accountName: Text("username"),
        accountEmail: Text("email"),
```